# Files in Repos enabled but not working / import modules using databricks feature Repos

Tags: python, git, module, databricks, databricks-repos

I follow all the steps to organize .py files and import them as module using this new DBR feature Files in Repos, but Im still getting same error "No module named".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BSKCx.png)

What I've done:

- check cluster version . Its a 9.1. I also talk to the admins that can enable/disable the toggle File in Repos feature. Everything is ok. They activate and deactivate to test.
- I deleted and reimport the repo from github
- I create new .py files and checked it's not a notebook file
- Im using the full folder path styles folder.subfolder.file
- I tried importing a repo file to another using sys.path tried in the same repo, the find the location but don't recognize as a module
- I read some Stack entries with people that had this problem, but they were using old DBR version.
- I can use git features and also view and edit .py files and text files as well.

No options worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This issue usually occurs in two cases:

- Databricks Repos aren't enabled
- Databricks Repos are enabled only for DBR 11+

So to use files in repos with DBR 9.1 you need to make sure that repos are enabled, and allowed for DBR 8.4+ as it's shown on the screenshot:

[image]